# Will using data management-> export data delete all records including attachments in salesforce

Tags: data

I want to keep a dummy copy of all the data for a custom object including notes and attachment for a custom object. As a result I am using data export using data management to export the data. Will this delete data as well in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [this](https://login.salesforce.com/ui/setup/export/DataExportPage/d?setupid=DataManagementExport), then no, your data will still be in your database.  You are merely exporting a copy.  :-)